# How to hide collapsible Bootstrap navbar on click in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, navbar

I use bootstrap responsive Navbar in VueJs, but it can not colse after click the link. Any way to do this? I don't want to use jQuery method.Thanks.

html navbar:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </div>

    <script>
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        
      }
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data() {
  return {
   show: true
  }
},
methods: {
  toggleNavbar() {
   this.show = !this.show;
  }
}
```

Comment: I used this method, but the navbar will lose the animation.